# Pandas: assign values to a column, as long as a condition persists and a certain value appears in another column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe including a certain condition, a counter of how many consecutive times the condition occurs, and a certain value, that looks like this:

```
         date                condition         count        Value1    Value2
    01,01,2018 08:00             A               1            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:01             A               2            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:02             A               3            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:03             B               1            1         1
    01,01,2018 08:04             B               2            0         1
    01,01,2018 08:05             B               3            0         1
    01,01,2018 08:06             B               4            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:07             C               1            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:08             C               2            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:09             C               3            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:10             C               4            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:11             C               5            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:12             A               1            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:13             A               2            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:14             B               1            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:15             B               2            0         1
    01,01,2018 08:16             B               3            0         1
    01,01,2018 08:17             C               1            0         0
```

I would like to add another column "error" which has value 1 under the condition:
if value1=1 and condition=B when count=1, then assign error=1 as long as value2=1.

It should look like:

```
         date                condition         count        Value1    Value2    error 
    01,01,2018 08:00             A               1            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:01             A               2            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:02             A               3            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:03             B               1            1         1        1
    01,01,2018 08:04             B               2            0         1        1
    01,01,2018 08:05             B               3            0         1        1
    01,01,2018 08:06             B               4            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:07             C               1            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:08             C               2            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:09             C               3            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:10             C               4            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:11             C               5            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:12             A               1            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:13             A               2            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:14             B               1            0         0        0
    01,01,2018 08:15             B               2            0         1        0
    01,01,2018 08:16             B               3            0         1        0
    01,01,2018 08:17             C               1            0         0        0
```

Please note that the second time the condition B occurs, value1 never gets equal to 1, so even if value2=1 there is no error.

I have tried things like:

```
df['error']=np.where(((df['value1']==1) & (df['condition']=='B') & df['value2']==1)) | ((df['error'].shift(1)=='1')&(df['value2']==1))),'1', 0)
```

but it gives me key error, because I am calling `df['error'].shift(1)=='1'` in the where-conditions while the column itself "doesn't exist yet".
Any idea? thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: your conditions are quite confusing, you say **if value1=1 and condition=B, then assign error=1 as long as value2=1** so the condition is value1=1 and condition=B and value2 =1?

Comment: you say 'it should like like:' but then your error column is wrong, so it should look like that or not?

Comment: yes, you are right, I should have expressed it better. the condition is: 
Condition=B, value1=1 on the first time condition=B appears, and error=1 continues as long as value2=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#conditions
mask = (df['Value1']==1) & (df['condition']=='B') & (df['Value2']==1)
#series for unique consecutive values
a = df['Value2'].ne(df['Value2'].shift()).cumsum()
#per each consecutive group cal cumulative sum, convert to boolean and then to integers
df['error'] = mask.groupby(a).cumsum().astype(bool).astype(int)
print (df)
                date condition  count  Value1  Value2  error
0   01,01,2018 08:00         A      1       0       0      0
1   01,01,2018 08:01         A      2       0       0      0
2   01,01,2018 08:02         A      3       0       0      0
3   01,01,2018 08:03         B      1       1       1      1
4   01,01,2018 08:04         B      2       0       1      1
5   01,01,2018 08:05         B      3       0       1      1
6   01,01,2018 08:06         B      4       0       0      0
7   01,01,2018 08:07         C      1       0       0      0
8   01,01,2018 08:08         C      2       0       0      0
9   01,01,2018 08:09         C      3       0       0      0
10  01,01,2018 08:10         C      4       0       0      0
11  01,01,2018 08:11         C      5       0       0      0
12  01,01,2018 08:12         A      1       0       0      0
13  01,01,2018 08:13         A      2       0       0      0
14  01,01,2018 08:14         B      1       0       0      0
15  01,01,2018 08:15         B      2       0       1      0
16  01,01,2018 08:16         B      3       0       1      0
17  01,01,2018 08:17         C      1       0       0      0
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael . However, it produces a result where I have error=1 just in line 3, where condition=B, value1=1 and value2=1.

Comment: There was an error because I was expressing value2 as a formula, now works fine :D thank you again!